# Zsh Slow in Dir of Git Repo

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I am using zsh shell and it has become very slow running any commands such as 'ls' 'cd' in directories that are Git Repo. In bash it works fine and fast. I also notice that the title of shell displays 'git' with spinning wheel on side. it appears "git" is called after executing 'ls', 'cd' not giving the control back and making it extremely slow ...and painful:)

I upgraded the latest Git 2.1.2, zsh 5.0.7. I am on Mac 10.9.2

How would you go about troubleshooting zsh shell? Thank You for help

Comment: Check if your `PS1` uses any of git prompt function.

Answer (score 1):

You likely have either:

- `git` getting called by your prompt: `echo $PS1 $PS2`
- `git` getting called by any of the many hook functions in zsh http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Hook-Functions

Likely, the easiest way to find it out is to start zsh with `zsh -x` and then move into your git repositories. It should show you what is going on.